# Error while parsing XML document in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, minidom

I'm trying to write a simple script that parses my XML document to get `name` from all `<xs:element>` tags. I'm using minidom (is there a better way?) Here is my code so far:

```
import csv
from xml.dom import minidom

xmldoc = minidom.parse('core.xml')
core = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('xs:element')

print(len(core))
print(core[0].attributes['name'].value)

for x in core:
    print(x.attributes['name'].value)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/XML Parsing/test.py", line 9, in <module>
   print(core[0].attributes['name'].value)
File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 522, in __getitem__
   return self._attrs[attname_or_tuple]
KeyError: 'name'
```

Comment: It would appear that `core[0].attributes` does not contain an item `name`. Without the file, it is impossible to help you debug. Try to work your way through the data structure and find the earliest point where an error occurs, maybe that will help you understand the issue.

Comment: so There is no attribute Named "name", make a Check with if "name" in core[0].attribute: than get the value, and use cElementTree for XML parsing

Comment: @sobek Yeah, I just realized that I was looking within the wrong tag, it's not supposed to be xs:element. Very silly error on my part.

Comment: @AriGold see above. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As you have the tag name, you don't need to add the index.

Just replace with the following code:

```
print(core.attributes['name'].value)
```